# Executing eclipse plug-in with maven

Tags: eclipse-plugin, protocol-buffers, maven-plugin, protobuf-java

I am working on a protobuf plugin project where I have a bundle of protobuf dependencies imported as a plug-in dependency to my protobuf plugin.

One of the dependencies is the protoc-jar-maven-plugin to generate java classes from the .proto files.

My problem is that I am not sure how I execute this in my pom.xml file?

I have the protoc jars in my plug-in dependencies folder, but my pom.xml does not seem to recognize the artifactID. "Plugin could not be resolved". It's the first time I write something like this, so not sure how it all works.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
             <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                 <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.11.4</version>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>run</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <protocVersion>3.11.4</protocVersion>
                             <inputDirectories>
                                 <include>src/main/resources</include>
                             </inputDirectories>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>
                 </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I am not sure if this is even possible so I looked into running my plug-in dependency through the eclipse run configurations but cannot find any information on how to configure it.

Comment: Note that Eclipse plug-ins and Maven plug-ins are completely different things and can't be interchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it is not possible to induce an automatic execution of the plugin through maven if I import it through eclipse dependencies?

Comment: If it is an Eclipse plug-in it has to run in a full OSGi environment with all the services that provides - maven is not an OSGi environment.